# Training a DNN with various noise standard deviation

Tags: keras, noise

I'm coming with a question concerning training with noise.
I do have a DNN whose first layer is a gaussian noise layers define by a stddev

```
model.add(GaussianNoise(stddev, input_shape=(41,)))
```

The `stddev` can then be changed easily from a model to another, but what if i want to change dynamically the noise level during the training process ?

I would like for example to train a model with a given dataset and a `stddev` of 0.1 (let's say with 10 epochs).
And then continue training the same model with the same or other dataset, but with a `stddev` of 0.02 (again 10 epochs for example).

I'm kind of struggling with changing dynamically the `stddev` ...
Any idea are welcome !
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it, thanks !
If it can helps someone else, that's how i did it:
My initial ML structure is defined through a function.
and below is the callback function

```
stddev=[0.02, 0.01]      # I use 2 stddev for the example
epoch_ch_stddev=5     # I want to run 5 epochs with the first stddev and then switch to the second one
model = create_model(stddev[0])    # creation of the ML structure

model.fit(X, y, epochs = 10, batch_size=1000, callbacks=[noise_change()])   # callback function for changing the stddev during the epochs.

class noise_change(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch==epoch_ch_stddev:
            self.model.layers[0].stddev=stddev[1]
        print('updating sttdev in training')
        print('Current stddev: ', self.model.layers[0].stddev)
```